# How can I grep in a loop?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, grep

I have a file containing text in separate lines.

```
text1
text2
text3
textN
```

I have a directory with many files. I want to grep for each line in the of this specific directory. What is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no need to loop, you can do use `grep` with the `-f` option to get patterns from a file:

```
grep -f pattern_file files*
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

#### Test

```
$ cat a1
hello
how are you?

$ cat a2
bye
hello

$ cat pattern
hello
bye

$ grep -f pattern a*
a1:hello
a2:bye
a2:hello
```

Comment: Of course, `*` may match directories as well, and then you'll get spammed with a bunch of `grep: a_directory: Is a directory` messages.

Comment: @kojiro note that my solution does not contain `*` alone, but `files*`. However, for the case you comment an alternative could be to do `find . -type f -maxdepth 0 -exec grep -f pattern_file {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard bash loop for this as well :

```
for i in text*; do grep "pattern" $i; done
```

or even better option without loop :

```
grep "pattern" text*
```

If you press tab after the `*` then shell will expand it to the files that satisfy the condition.