# How to pipe a file to Find command in cmd.dir/s *.txt>search.txt|find "name" is not working

Tags: c, cmd, pipe

I want to Find wether a file named name is there or not without using dir/s subhang.txt. can you tell me how to do it using pipes and how to connect two C programs using Pipes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be asking two different questions - one about how to find if a file exists and one about using pipes to connect programs. You'll get better answers if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry,I was bit more Enthusiastic learning about PIPES.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command:

```
dir/s *.txt >search.txt | find "name"
```

... doesn't work because the output of `dir/s` goes into the file `search.txt`. If you try:

```
dir/s *.txt | find "name"
```

... that will output the results of the `find` to the console, or

```
dir/s *.txt | find "name" >search.txt
```

... will output the result of the find to the file `search.txt`.

Comment: The format of find is `FIND <flags> "search string" <path>`. Is there a way to specify the parameter of `FIND` to which the output of the first program (`dir` in this case) should be piped?

Comment: @MinhTran: the output of the first program is piped into `find`. I'm not clear what it would mean to pipe the output of `dir` into a parameter of `find`.

Comment: Suppose you have `MyPatterns.txt` in which each line contains a regex pattern to be substituted into the `"Search String"` parameter of `FIND`. Is there a way to pipe each line of that file to `FIND` as a search string? And suppose you have `MyPaths.txt` which contains a list of file paths to search for a given `"search string"`, is there a way to pipe that into `FIND` as the argument to `<path>`?

Comment: @MinhTran: The short answer is "no" to both questions as long as you are using Windows `cmd` and `find`. If you want to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) with the `bash` shell and Unix `grep`, `grep -f <filename>` gets regex search patterns from the file `<filename>`, which would deal with the first problem. Similarly, reading paths from a file and searching each of them could easily be done in a loop within `bash` (though it would be harder or impossible in a Windows batch file), e.g. [How can I grep in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273766/how-can-i-grep-in-a-loop)

Comment: @MinhTran: If you would like to ask a separate question based on your comment, I expect you will receive more complete answers.